# How to properly consume message using RabbitMQ with MassTransit in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I am implementing application in microservices architecture. I would like to attach some kind of event store to my solution. I am new to messaging with RabbitMQ, and probably i've configured something improperly. Let's simplify my solution, so imagine i have a simple common service which has to broadcast some messages to the bus. To register broker dependencies i use the following code:

```
internal static IServiceCollection RegisterRabbitMQDependencies(this IServiceCollection services,   
    IConfiguration configuration)                                                                   
{                                                                                                   
    var rabbitMQSettings = configuration                                                             
        .GetSection(RabbitMQSettingsSectionKey)                                                      
        .Get<RabbitMQSettings>();                                                                   
                                                                                                    
    services                                                                                        
        .AddSingleton(serviceProvider => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configurator =>
        {                                                                                           
            configurator                                                                            
                .Host(rabbitMQSettings.HostName,                                                    
                    rabbitMQSettings.VirtualHostName,                                               
                    hostConfigurator =>                                                             
                    {                                                                               
                        hostConfigurator.Username(rabbitMQSettings.UserName);                       
                        hostConfigurator.Password(rabbitMQSettings.Password);                       
                    });                                                                             
                                                                                                    
            configurator.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Fanout;                                        
        }))                                                                                         
        .AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>())     
        .AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>())
        .AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>())                 
        .Configure<RabbitMQSettings>(configuration.GetSection(RabbitMQSettingsSectionKey));         
                                                                                                    
    return services;                                                                                
}
```

It has no consumer due to our simplification - it only has to publish some message to the bus. The messages from the service are published properly because i can notice them in RabbitMq Management System.
The problem is any of my consumers don't respond to the corresponding message (probably due to some configuration errors). Back to the implementation - i have an event store (different container). My event store has to handle all the integration events which are travelling across the bus. I've configured the communication in the event store like shown below:

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterMessagingDependencies(this IServiceCollection services,               
    IConfiguration configuration) =>                                                                           
        services                                                                                               
            .AddMassTransit(configurator =>                                                                    
                {                                                                                              
                    configurator.AddConsumer<EventHandler>();                                                  
                })                                                                                             
            .AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>                                   
            {                                                                                                  
                cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h => {                                                              
                    h.Username("guest");                                                                       
                    h.Password("guest");                                                                       
                });                                                                                            
            }))                                                                                                
            .RegisterEndpointsDependencies();
```

The connection parameters are correct, i've checked them few times. As you have noticed - i have only one consumer called "EventHandler" which has to handle all the IntegrationEvents. Here i attach the definition of EventHandler class, and it's parent:

```
public abstract class IntegrationEventHandler<TIntegrationEvent> : IIntegrationEventHandler<TIntegrationEvent>,
    IConsumer<TIntegrationEvent> where TIntegrationEvent : class, IIntegrationEvent
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TIntegrationEvent> context) =>
        await HandleAsync(context.Message);
    
    public abstract Task HandleAsync(TIntegrationEvent @event);
}

public sealed class EventHandler : IntegrationEventHandler<IIntegrationEvent>
{
    private readonly IEventRepository _eventRepository;

    public EventHandler(IEventRepository eventRepository)
    {
        _eventRepository = eventRepository;
    }
    
    public override async Task HandleAsync(IIntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        var readyToBeSavedEvent = new Event(@event);
        await _eventRepository.CreateAsync(readyToBeSavedEvent);
        await _eventRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

EventHandler base class implements the IConsumer interface, so i thought it should be somehow connected with all integration events occured on the bus. But the problem is the HandleAsync method is never called, although some events are published. Additionaly i append the code responsible for publishing my events:

```
public async Task PublishAsync(params IIntegrationEvent[] events)
{
    var globalPublicationTasks = events
        .Select(@event =>
        {
            @event.PublishedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            @event.JsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@event);

            return _publishEndpoint.Publish(@event);
        });

    await Task.WhenAll(globalPublicationTasks);
}
```

Am i missing something? What am i doing wrong? I would expect that HandleAsync method is called when some integration event is published on the bus. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using `AddMassTransit` properly. You also don't start the bus on the consumer side.

It's all [properly documented](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core), you just need to copy-paste the example.

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<EventConsumer>();

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("event-listener", e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumer<EventConsumer>(context);
                });
            });
        });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
    }
```